# How to iterate over all children elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to iterate over all children elements?

I have an array that has an infinite number of nested childrens, how do I output all of them?

```
const data = [
    { title: "Mark", children: [{ title: "Alex" }] },
    {
      title: "Alisa",
      children: [{ title: "Bob", children: [{ title: "Jacob" }] }]
    }
];
```

***I only go through two levels, but there can be as many as you like.***

```
{data.map((item) => {
        return (
          <div>
            {item.title}
            {item.children.map((item) => item.title)}
          </div>
        );
      })}
```

Comment: Putting `<div>` into JavaScript like that is not valid syntax. If you're using a framework that allows that, add the tag to the question.

Comment: Typically you'd use recursion and call the function for each *title* property, passing *children* if it exists.

Comment: @Barmar the OP's obviously using React. Why don't you just edit?

Comment: @code I can never remember which syntax is react, vue, angular,  etc. since I don't use any of them.

Comment: @Barmar React uses JSX, Vue uses standard JS or SFC (typically a page with a `<template>` tag, a `<style>` tag, and a `<script>` tag), and in Angular `ng-` is everywhere.

Comment: @code Without actual experience with them it's not going to stick in my memory, although I think I knew about the `ng-` stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the mapper a named function, and then you'll be able to call it recursively.

```
const renderItem = item => (
  <div>
    {item.title}
    {item.children?.map(renderItem)}
  </div>
);
return data.map(renderItem);
```